# gnu::warn_unused_result attribute ignored if return class has destructor

Tags: c++, g++, language-lawyer

I want to warn a user if he/she does not save a return value of some function, but it does not work if the function returns a class which has a non-default destructor.

Assume the following code:

```
struct A {};
struct B { ~B() {} };

[[ gnu::warn_unused_result ]]
A foo() { return A{}; }

[[ gnu::warn_unused_result ]]
B bar() { return B{}; }

int main()
{
    foo(); // warning
    bar(); // no warning
    return 0;
}
```

When compiled with g++ 6.2.1, only `foo()` generates a warning:

```
$ g++ -Wall -Wextra ./test.cpp 
./test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
./test.cpp:13:9: warning: ignoring return value of ‘A foo()’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
     foo();
         ^
```

I understand that a call to a destructor of `B` might be considered a "usage of a result", but the questions are:

- Is this an expected behaviour or is this a bug/feature in g++?
- Is there a way to force a compiler to issue a warning in this case?
- Will C++17's `[[ nodiscard ]]` behave the same?

Comment: I would think this is a bug. But I don't know what `GCC` authors intended. The problem with this is the behavior can change from one build to the next if the class of the return object is slightly modified. I can't see how anyone would find that desirable. What about library objects your project has no control over?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this an expected behaviour or is this a bug/feature in g++?

It's a QoI issue, as are all warnings like this. gcc 7 *does* issue a warning for `bar()`, so while it's not a bug to not issue a warning it's more of a missed feature in gcc 6.2.

> Will C++17's `[[ nodiscard ]]` behave the same?

This is also implementation defined. There is a non-normative note in the standard in [dcl.attr.nodiscard]:

> Appearance of a
>   nodiscard call as a potentially-evaluated discarded-value expression (Clause 5) is discouraged unless explicitly
>   cast to void. **Implementations are encouraged to issue a warning in such cases.** This is typically because
>   discarding the return value of a nodiscard call has surprising consequences.

Implementations are not *required* to issue a warning in this case. But they will likely try to do so.

Comment: What does QoI stand for? Quality of Implementation (a wild guess)?

Comment: @Kane Yep. Good guess.